# Modifying the argument passed to jQuery done() callback following a successful AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Here's the scenario:

I need to fetch some JSON data via AJAX from the server (ASP.NET MVC application + ServiceStack services). If the user's session expires then instead of getting back JSON I get a redirect to the login page, which gets automatically executed by jQuery, so the result of the AJAX call ends up being the raw HTML of the login form. I need to handle these two cases differently:

- if the result is JSON then use it to update the UI using the `.done()` promise
- if the result is HTML then pop up a login dialog.

So I have to modify the argument passed to the `done()` callback. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
function getSomeData() 
{
    return $.ajax(
    {
        /* 
            ...set my AJAX config options... 
        */,
        error: function(xhr, status, errorText)
        {
            // handle the error
        },
        success: function(data) 
        {
            // if the AJAX call returned a login form instead of expected JSON 
            // result (because the user's session has expired) then show a 
            // login dialog and resolve the jQuery promise with 'null' instead 
            // of original 'data'

            if (isLoginFormHTML(data)) 
            {
                showModalLoginDialog(data);
                data = null;    // neither this...
                return null;    // ... nor this seem to work!
            }
        }
    });
}

function updateUI()
{
    getSomeData().done(function(jsonData)
    {
        if (jsonData)
        {
            // do something 
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, regardless of whether I do `data = null` or `return null` in my `success` function, the argument passed to the `done()` callback contains the original `data` returned from the server, which may be the HTML of the login form if the session has expired.

So the question is, how do I tell jQuery to pass something else to `done()`?

**P.S.** Of course, I could perform the `isLoginFormHTML()` check inside the `updateUI` method but I'm trying to avoid that in order to keep the data-retrieval and UI-update logic separate.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but my first impulse would be to return an error in the case of a session expiration, rather than HTML.  You can then handle that specific error by pulling and displaying the login form.

Also, done() gets called even if there IS an error, so you'll probably want to use getSomeData().success() regardless of how you handle the login HTML.

Comment: Use `.then` instead of `success:`

Comment: Dave: I have no control over the server's response because the redirect to the login page is done automatically by FormsAuthentication that my ASP.NET MVC application uses.

Comment: Benjamin Gruenbaum: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks promising. I'll update my post once I find a solution.

Comment: @CaspianCanuck that's the solution, `success:` is not a promise continuation. Return `$.ajax(..).then(function(){ ...`, if you want to signal an error, I suggest you throw instead to cause the promise to reject (like a synchronous throw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a promise on the values you need by using `.then`, one of the cool things about promises is that they chain.

```
function getSomeData() 
{
    return $.ajax({
        /* 
            ...set my AJAX config options... 
        */,
        error: function(xhr, status, errorText)
        {
            // handle the error
        }).then(function(data){

            if (isLoginFormHTML(data)) {
                showModalLoginDialog(data);
                throw new Error("Unauthorized");..
            }
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

Which would allow you to do:

```
    getSomeData().done(function(jsonData){
        //yay data   
    }).fail(function(){
       //no data
    });
```